# Replacing EL in JSP with SpEL from Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

Tired of old EL in JSP not being able to invoke methods on beans etc.

Can I use [SpEL from Spring 3.0](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html#new-feature-el) in my JSP:s?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<s>The upcoming</s> Spring Framework 3.0.1 release adds a new [spring:eval](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/spring.tld.html#spring.tld.eval) JSP tag that allows you to evaluate SpEL expressions from JSP pages.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
```

Future versions will add native integration with JSP 2.1 or > engines via a Unified EL adaption layer.

Answer (score 3):

It would be nice, wouldn't it, but no, JSP EL is a function of the JSP compiler. The best you could do would be to write a custom taglib which evaluated contained SpEL expressions, which would be rather clunky.

Answer (score 1):

If an upgrade is possible, you can get method invocation support in the latest JSP EL/Java EE implementations (e.g. Java EE 6 using GlassFish v3). The [JUEL](http://juel.sourceforge.net/index.html) (an EL implementation) [doc page suggests](http://juel.sourceforge.net/guide/service.html) you can upgrade either by putting the classes into your JRE's ext directory or by putting them in `WEB-INF/lib` and relying on the SPI mechanism (this depends on your container supporting this). The latest JUEL version supports method invocations.

I don't know enough about the Spring implementation to know how they plug in their EL support.

Comment: Is it possible to use JUEL in Tomcat? And there won't be any conflicts with SpEL?

Answer (score 1):

I use JBoss EL within Tomcat in the manner described by McDowell.  I included the jboss-el.jar in WEB-INF/lib for my application and added this snippet to web.xml:

```
  <!-- jboss el expressions allow method params -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
  </context-param>
```