# Can we use spring expression language in jsp?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

can we use spring expression language in jsp like #{object.property}
remember object already present in context factory.

When use `${'hello'.toUpperCase().substring(0,3)}` works fine. is it use Spring EL or jsp EL ?

I had tried this example but i got an exception ?

```
<% 
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
        StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
        context.registerFunction("reverseString",
        StringUtils.class.getDeclaredMethod("reverseString", String.class));    
    %>
     ${#reverseString('hello')}
```

Comment: You can use JSTL(Java standard tag library) which has all the methods and support.

Comment: i want to know how to let jsp use spring el ?

Answer (score 1):

The first answer in the linked question (using the <spring:eval> tag) is a partial solution:
[Replacing EL in JSP with SpEL from Spring 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945143/replacing-el-in-jsp-with-spel-from-spring-3-0)

The other answer in the above question was to replace the Expression Factory in your webapp by setting the relevant property in web.xml, but it looks like the Spring team decided not to build an implementation of it:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6080